# 4 "Undefined symbols for architecture i386:" errors when trying to compile

Tags: ios, objective-c, architecture

I am getting these 4 errors when trying to compile. I've tried some of the other solutions and none of them seem to work. Below is the error log:

Thanks for the help!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_kJAHeadlineViewHeight", referenced from:
  -[MasterViewController minimizeTableView] in MasterViewController-A88C42CB51855C04.o
  -[MasterViewController scrollViewDidScroll:] in MasterViewController-A88C42CB51855C04.o
 "_kJAMinimizedVisibleTopHeight", referenced from:
  -[MasterViewController minimizeTableView] in MasterViewController-A88C42CB51855C04.o
 "_kJATableViewAnimationSpeed", referenced from:
 -[MasterViewController minimizeTableView] in MasterViewController-A88C42CB51855C04.o
 -[MasterViewController maximizeTableView] in MasterViewController-A88C42CB51855C04.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I call it in my code but could you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're including a third party code library? If so, it may not be built to run on the simulator. You may have to test on an iOS device only.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen messages like that when I forget to include all my .m files in the target.

Answer (score 0):

Those are defined in `JAConstants.m`.  Make sure in your project compile files list in your project build settings that you have `JAConstants.m` listed.  If it's not being compiled but you are still referencing against `JAConstants.h` then you will get that error.

Comment: This didn't work. I added that and all my views and resources to be compiled and it still shows 4 errors.